# POST запросы на file_get_contents или fsockopen

Tags: php, api, file-get-contents, ucoz

у меня есть сайт на козе, мне нужно к нему через API делать POST запросы, НО из за отсутствия CURL на бесплатном хостинге, я не понимаю как сделать что то аналогичное...

```
curl --header Authorization: OAuth oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Fsvetofor.org.ua", oauth_consumer_key="Denis7791024", oauth_nonce="7eeb3c1f42ef8a6c1d3abd837fb3433d", oauth_signature="kJ2p1EFyzTdBlHEpT%2FGNViYsMSU%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1548191023", oauth_token="C6mgkrkf9jwBCNaN.DJrCeV6d83W3yoiahrXCv9p" --request POST http://svetofor.org.ua/uapi/board/
```

Пробовал через file_get_contents, работает только с GET запросами, а добавлять информацию на сайт через API я могу только через POST запросы. Очень благодарен за ранее.

Answer (score 2):

POST запросы с file_get_contents

```
$url='http://google.com';
$opts=['http' => ['method' => 'POST', 'header' => '','content' => 'login=user&password=pass']];
$file=file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($opts));
```

Comment: Да, действительно, пост запросы fgt тоже умеет! Но как быть с файлами!? Нужно, что бы фото товаров передавались, а кроме как cURL пока ничего не получалось. И к стати когда запрос с помощью fgt делаешь ошибка 400 или 401....

Comment: @MARSHAL и файлы может отправлять, а ошибка 400/401 вероятно из-за неправильных запросов, или header надо тщательнее подделывать

Comment: Возможно вы правы, увы пришлось переходить на OpenCart из за необоснованных ограничений в работе с API конструктора...